# Rails 5.2 migrations conundrum, create primary key and foreign keys

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my migrations, but they won't work, trying to add foreign key on products from primary key in categories
20180724203015_create_categories.rb

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
   def change
    create_table :categories, id: false do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.integer :category_id, primary_key: true, auto_increment: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

20180724203105_create_products.rb

```
 class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|

      t.string :name
      t.references :category_id, foreign_key: true, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

however this always ends with an error, cannot add foreign key contraint

Comment: Say more about "will not work".

Comment: I am trying to add products to categories, within the site, however nothing is stored inthe database because it gives an error message saying that category must exist, I presume because :category_id in products table remains empty, I would like it to populate with the associated category_id from which I am creating a product...

Comment: actually all I want is primary key :category_id on categories, and foreign key :category_id on products, so that I may associate tables.

Comment: Why are you using `category_id` as the primary key on `categories` instead of the conventional `id`?

Comment: i'm not sure how to associate tables from :id to :id to each, does rails create category_id?  In other words, how would i associate tables from :id to :id from categories to products?

Comment: You can just reference the model name....`t.references :category, foreign_key: true`, and keep the default primary key

Comment: How do I include the category_id <- correct? in my products_controller?

Comment: In what context? Please post your products controller so people can answer the question...but, for a common answer, you can grab the product's category with `@category = @product.category`, or, if you need to grab the category from params...`@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])`.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails embraces the *convention over configuration* principle. That means if you follow the Rails conventions things will be much easier and almost no configuration is needed.

In your migrations you decided to fight one of the Rails conventions: The primary key of a database is stored in an `id` column. When you decide to not follow this convention then you cannot simply use the `references` method anymore without telling Rails how you set up your database instead.

My advice is: Unless you have a very, very good reason, do not fight against Rails conventions. It will not only make this task (database migration) more complex, but it also increased the risk that something else needs more configuration (ActiveRecord models for example) or that things might break in gems or when you update Rails to a newer version.

That said: Change your migration to use the Rails conventions:

```
# 20180724203015_create_categories.rb
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
   def change
    create_table :categories do |t| # <- create an `id` column per default
      t.string :name
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# 20180724203105_create_products.rb
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.references :category, foreign_key: true # <- just name the relation

      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is to remove t.integer :category_id, and rely on rails' :id column for each table, references can be made with @category or with @product, and as mentioned in the comments - @category = Cateogory.find(params[:id]) or Category.find(params[:category_id]) as I believe that is how it is referenced in routes.   Thank you.